# Install wordpress on subdomains

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

I need some help with wordpress. I have got a wordpress on my main domain and I would like to use another wordpress on my subdomains with the same theme, plugins, blog pages and posts but different links in my blog posts. I want to know how I can change the links in my blog posts for the main domain and the subdomains?

Do I need to create a subdirectory folder and a different database name for each subdomain and do I also need to copy the wordpress files from the main domain to the subddirectories folder so I could be able to create the username and password for the subdomains and then login in the wordpress for each subdomain to change the links in the blog posts?

I want you to understand that I want to use the main domain and subdomains to use the same theme, same plugins, same blog posts and same pages but the links in the blog posts have to be different, because I am going to use different traffic sources on each subdomain to track for clicks and sales, example: my main domain will be use for google traffic, the blog subdomain is for facebook and the other subdomain is for easyhits4u. I can track the clicks and sales for google and other traffic sources because the links in the blog posts for the main domain and subdomains would not be the same.

If I use the same links in the blog posts for the main domain and the subdomains, I would not know how many clicks and sales I would get from each traffic source I use and I would not know where the clicks and sales are coming from. That is why I want to use it seperate so I can track it easy.

Comment: wordpress have options for multisites. Maybe this is exactly what you are searching for: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Just curious, @Sysix, why not post this as an answer?  It is correct, I think.

Comment: because it's only a hint and not a solution for his problem. He must actually fetch then the data from the other site.

Comment: @Sysix thank you for this, would multisite allow me to change the links in the blog posts when I edit my blog posts and change the links in the images?

Comment: Just by curiosity, if you have the same posts but not the same url, does google not see duplicate content?

Comment: @AlexVand No it don't but I want to use different links in the blog posts when you click on the ads because I want to track where I get the leads from, where I make the sales from and what traffic source I use otherwise I would not be able to know. Is it possible to change the links in the blog posts when I have added the subdomain in the cpanel that point to the public_html folder that come with the same webpage as the main domain but I cant change the links in the blog posts?

Comment: I have been told I need to add multisite and copy the wordpress to my subdomain folder so I could login and change the link in the subdomain wordpress? is that the only way I could do or what?

Answer (score 1):

To go a little further about the comment of @Sysix :

As far as I know, Wordpress Multisite allow you to have **one folder that hold all of your websites**. Your websites url can be subdomains or subfolders based (but this one not need to have a **real subfolder**, it's only about the url)

- subdomain.example.com
- example.com/subdomain

At my last work, the php developper made a plugin or something that allow you to have different urls for each site of the network.

- example.com
- example2.com
- etc.

(I'm gonna search some informations about it, if you are interested in)

Websites are handled with the **database only**, and if you take a look at the wordpress database after you have create a new site in the network, you will get **new tables** wp_posts, wp_meta etc. with a number after them that is related to the **site id**.

So i think that the best way for you is to make one website, create all the post, the pages, and when it's done, duplicate it in a new site in the network.

You can use the plugin in the link below to duplicate a site of your network.

https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/

**Just a warning** : I know that this way it could works, but I also know there some conditions to make it works great. I can't remember exactly why but I seem to recall that you can't easily duplicate the main website of the Network. There was a workaround to do it but I don't remember exactly what was the issue, and how to resolved it.

I'm gonna search and test some stuff right now, so this answer is not definitive but it could get you on the way. I will edit it if i find or remember some important thing.

Sorry for this answer that is not really an answer, but in comment it was not possible to write all this ... Also if I said nonsense, please correct me, and I will edit the post as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but I am more interested to know if multisite would allow me to edit my blog post for the subdomain to change my own links?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying in that comment bro ... i'm not a native english, but i'm pretty sur it doesn't mean anything when you say "multisite would allow me to edit my blog post for the subdomain to change my own links?"